# N+1 Query on Sinatra app

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rails-activerecord

So i'm getting these three queries on my console:

```
D, [2014-05-30T09:41:15.504655 #4629] DEBUG -- :    (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts"  WHERE ("posts"."published_on" IS NOT NULL)
D, [2014-05-30T09:41:15.506857 #4629] DEBUG -- :   Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE ("posts"."published_on" IS NOT NULL)  ORDER BY published_on DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
D, [2014-05-30T09:41:15.513479 #4629] DEBUG -- :    (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(count_column) FROM (SELECT  1 AS count_column FROM "posts"  WHERE ("posts"."published_on" IS NOT NULL) LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0) subquery_for_count
```

I did google this and found this 'N+1 queries' and a whole lot but not real answers why; so i don't know if i should fix this or not, or how (im new to Ruby/sinatra)

On my code all i do is:

```
count = Post.where.not({published_on: nil}).count
....
@posts = Post.where.not({published_on: nil}).order("published_on DESC").limit(per_page).offset(offset)
```

In the middle i do some calculations with count to ge the offset, and after that a @post.length to know if i get any results.

My models are pretty simple, Post(w/has_many tags), Tag, and PostTags to associate both.

Any tip to change this, if i have to?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think this is a `N+1` problem?

Comment: Because i expect two queries instead of three. Also looking at similar questions that's what i found. I've no idea why the 3rd query occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An N+1 problem is relevant to queries where in ORM you want to fetch the children of a item, and find that the ORM queries them one-by-one (see [What is SELECT N+1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue)).

Your problem seems unrelated to this. I've tracked down your problem to this [code](https://github.com/rails/docrails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/calculations.rb#L234)(the hint was `subquery_for_count` in your logs):

> ```
> def execute_simple_calculation(operation, column_name, distinct) #:nodoc:
>   # Postgresql doesn't like ORDER BY when there are no GROUP BY
>   relation = unscope(:order)
>   ...
>   if operation == "count" && (relation.limit_value || relation.offset_value)
>     # Shortcut when limit is zero.
>     return 0 if relation.limit_value == 0
>
>     query_builder = build_count_subquery(relation, column_name, distinct)
>     bind_values = query_builder.bind_values + relation.bind_values
>   else
>   ...
> ```

...

> ```
> def build_count_subquery(relation, column_name, distinct)
>   column_alias = Arel.sql('count_column')
>   subquery_alias = Arel.sql('subquery_for_count')
> ```

This means that the relation calculations module will add the extra query if you mix `count` with `limit` or `offset`...

Comment: Thanks a lot, helped me out a lot to track my issue.